# How to tell to GIT, it should take care of only these and these sub-folders?

Tags: git, gitignore, mql4

I want to use git in a particular development environment.
MetaTrader 4.

The structure of development directory is fixed, it is of this type:

```
MQL4
  Expert
  Files
  imagery
  Include
  Indicators
```

Some directories come by default with sample files.
My idea would be to create directories under of these directories , and to indicate in .gitignore, I wish that only these directories have to be considered by git.

```
MQL4
  Expert
    MyGITExperts
  Files
  imagery
  Include
    MyGITInclude
  Indicators
    MyGITIndicators
```

My idea is a right one ?
Are there a better one?
How to tell to git, it should take care of only these and these sub-folders ?

Comment: You could try excluding everything with `*` and then excluding patterns from that expression using the `^` operator.

Comment: @Thom Wiggers Thanks it should work, but I don't try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is a way.

From git docs
Example to exclude everything except a specific directory foo/bar (note the /* - without the slash, the wildcard would also exclude everything within foo/bar):

```
$ cat .gitignore
# exclude everything except directory foo/bar
/*
!/foo
/foo/*
!/foo/bar
```

http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

In your case
im assuming that MQL4 is inside your project root(where .git file is there)

```
/*
!/MQL4
/MQL4/*
!/MQL4/Expert/MyGITExperts
!/MQL4/Files
!/MQL4/imagery
!/MQL4/Include/MyGITInclude
!/MQL4/Indicators/MyGITIndicators
```

This is generally a bad idea when you have large number of such folders

Comment: You should also add `!.gitignore`, otherwise `.gitignore` will be ignored as well because of `/*`.

Comment: Hi Darshan,
MQL4 was the project ROOT.
Then I change your code to :

/*
!.gitignore
!/Experts
/Experts/*
!/Experts/MyGITExperts

!/Include
/Include/*
!/Include/MyGITInclude

!/Indicators
/Indicators/*
!/Indicators/MyGITIndicators


It seen to work, but I think I change my mind.
It seen to me too complicated.
One repository equal one platform.
And I will fire samples.

@markusk Thanks I added it.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore),

> gitignore - Specifies intentionally untracked files to ignore

So first you need to mention the files you dont want to track and then include the ones you want to take care of.

For example, Lets says you have a couple of other directories/files in `Include/`
You would need to ignore those first and then un-ignore the `Include/MyGITInclude/` directory explicitly

```
/Include/*
!/Include/MyGITInclude/
```

This way you get all of the MyGITInclude/ directory, including subdirectories and their files. Do the same for other directories/sub-directories.

Cheers!